# How to make sure that only 3 out of the 5 numbers are the same?

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I am using clpfd and I have 5 variables, how can I make sure that maximum 3 out of these 5 variables will be the same? 
For example:
1, 1, 1, 2, 2 -> allowed
1, 1, 1, 2, 3 -> allowed
1, 1, 1, 1, 4 -> not allowed
...

I think it would work like this:

```
number(N1),
number(N2),
number(N3),
number(N4),
number(N5),
((N1 #= N2 #/\ N1 #= N3) #==> (N1 #\= N4 #/\ N1 #\= N5)) #\/ ((N1 #= N2 #/\ N1 #= N4) #==> (N1 #\= N3 #/\ N1 #\= N5)) #\/ ...
```

But this solution seems too long and I was wondering if it could be solved with less code.

Comment: The maximum number of *ones* is `3`, or for all values?

Comment: For multiple values: N1, N2 ,.. are all in a domain like for example 1..10

Comment: And there don't have to be 3 ones: 1,2,3,4,5 would also be allowed.

Comment: So you really mean to say "a maximum of 3 out of 5 of the numbers are the same". Does order matter? For instance, do you consider, `[1,1,2,3,1]` the same as `[1,1,1,2,3]` or different solutions?

Comment: Yeah, and the order doesn't matter: [1,1,2,3,1] and [1,1,1,2,3] are both allowed.

Comment: `sort(Numbers, Sorted), length(Sorted, 3)` ?

Answer (score 0):

There you go!

Code:

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).

check([H1,H2,H3,H4]):- #\(H1#=H2#/\H2#=H3#/\H3#=H4),!.
check([H1,H2,H3,H4|T]):- #\(H1#=H2#/\H2#=H3#/\H3#=H4),check([H2,H3,H4|T]).

count_frequencies([],_,LIST,LIST).
count_frequencies([HEAD|TAIL],PREVIOUS,INIT,LIST):-
HEAD\=PREVIOUS,
count_frequencies(TAIL,HEAD,[HEAD-1|INIT],LIST).
count_frequencies([HEAD|TAIL],HEAD,[HEAD-F|T],LIST):-
    F2 is F+1,
    count_frequencies(TAIL,HEAD,[HEAD-F2|T],LIST).

max_frequency_is_3(NUMBERS,DOMAIN,RESULT):-
    length(LIST,NUMBERS),
    LIST ins DOMAIN,
    chain(LIST,#=<),
    check(LIST),
    label(LIST),
    count_frequencies(LIST,false,[],LIST2),
    length(RESULT,NUMBERS),
    global_cardinality(RESULT,LIST2),
    label(RESULT).
```

Example-query:

```
?- max_frequency_is_3(5,1..5,LIST).
```

Results:

```
L = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2] ;
L = [1, 1, 2, 1, 2] ;
L = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1] ;
L = [1, 2, 1, 1, 2] ;
L = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1] ;
...
```

Arguments of max_frequency_is_3/3 are..

NUMBERS: the amount of numbers you have - in your case it's 5

DOMAIN: the domain your numbers take a value in (f.e. 1..10, 3..7, etc.)

RESULT: the returning list / output.